# bulid 12v switch off circuit

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, 12v, battery-chemistry

i have a tv that works on 12v dc and also 220v Ac. i can attach both power cables. I run it on the 12v battery almost of the time but some times the 220v electricity is back so i have to make it work on it by remove the 12v dc blug and re-switch it on again so it can work on 220v blug. if i don't remove it the screen will still work on 12v blug even the 220v is excited. i need a simple circuit that can switch of the 12v blug once the220v ac is back.

note: i used a charger for my battery so once the 220v Ac is back the volt of the battery blug incrase from 12v to almost more than 13v.

any help please.

great thancks

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be a 230V relais. If the 230V get connected, it disconnects the TV of the 12 V power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCdjyS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If 230V is applied, the relais pulls and opens the switch. This disconnects the TV from the 12V power supply. If the 230AC leaves, the switch will jump back to its normal position and 12V is reconnected.

Comment: i need some circuit to switch the 12v blug one the 12v incrase to over 13v

Comment: Are you sure? ;-)

Comment: hhhhh, yes i am pretty sure :)

Comment: :-) Is the voltage of the Battery the only way to detect 230V is back? Why not detect it directly?

Comment: i think in this sice the charger will incrase the volt if the battery once 220v is back.  if you have any idea let me know but iver the 12v so it wil be easy to deal with rather than dealing with 220v ^_^

Comment: I don't like the idea of detecting the change of battery voltage. It may be unreliable if the battery is full or has high load.

Comment: so what you recommend

Comment: i recommend the circuit in my answer

Comment: great thanx i will try it

Comment: do you know how i can build an amp tester so i can know what is the amount of amp's in my battery